# Mediation analysis: How to interpret an insignificant indirect while other effects are significant?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

I performed a mediation analysis with package `**lavaan**` in R. My mediation analysis revealed:

Path `c` is significant (total effect); path `a` is significant; path `c'` is significant (direct effect); path `b` is  significant; path `ab` is not significant. How can I explain this model?
[image]

PHQ stands for depression, severe stands for illness perception, and QOLIE10 is for QOL.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to add the model specification in lavaan syntax, to make sure I understand your model correctly. From what you write above, you have a predictor X, a response Y, and mediating variable M. The direct path between X and Y is c', the path from X to M is a, the path from M to Y is b, the indirect path from X to Y is ab. I believe the most likely explanation is that there is no mediation. Only the direct effect of X on Y is significant, making the total effect significant. The effect of X on M is significant, but there is no mediation, because there is no effect of M on Y.

Comment: I apricate your help and sorry for my mistake as I said b is not significant while it was. I also have included the model and results. Please reconsider my question.

Comment: What Marjolein said still stands. Since ab is not statistically significant, you do not have evidence of a mediation effect in this case.